# Unknown limit of an array of area integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, list-manipulation, regions, integral-transforms

Could someone explain why Mathematica can't finish computing this limit (this is a limit of an array, when `n -> Infinity` (`n` is an integer), whose elements are area-integrals as shown):

```
 Limit[Integrate[(x^(2n) + y^(2n)) Boole[x^(2n) + y^(2n) < 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], n -> Infinity]
```

In the case when `n=2`, the integral is `Pi/2`, for `n=4` it is `(2 Gamma[1/4] Gamma[5/4])/(3 Sqrt[\[Pi]])`

Thanx

Comment: Your integrand does give values for some n, but not for others. For example, `n=2.1` gives a revealing error. Do you mean for `n` to be integer?

Comment: Yes, n is an integer, sorry I forgot to specify.

Answer (score 2):

I can get the integral by using the first quadrant (for positivity), placing an assumption on `n`, and recasting without `Boole` (I don't know why that was needed).

```
in = 4 Integrate[(x^(2 n) + y^(2 n)), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 
    0, (1 - x^(2 n))^(1/(2*n))}, Assumptions -> n >= 1]

(* Out[112]= (2^(2 - 1/n) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
  Gamma[1 + 1/(2 n)])/((1 + n) Gamma[(1 + n)/(2 n)]) *)
```

As @Belisarius notes, the limit is now straightforward.

```
Limit[in, n -> Infinity]

(* t[113]= 0 *)
```

Comment: The `Boole` is there to specify the area over which an integral is computed (i think this is one way to do that). For example when `n=2` the area is a circle with unit area, centered at the origin.

Comment: I realize why you had the Boole there. This is a perfectly appropriate usage but, for whatever reason, Integrate did not seem able to handle it. That's why I recast with the more awkward endpoint of integration.

Answer (score 1):

By manual inspection I got a closed formula for your integral:

```
s[n_] := 2/(n + 1) Gamma[1/(2 n)] Gamma[(2  n + 1)/(2 n)]/Gamma[1/n]
f[n_] := Integrate[(x^(2 n) + y^(2 n)) Boole[x^(2 n) + y^(2 n) < 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

For example

```
s[16] == f[16]
(*
 True
*)

Plot[s[x], {x, 1, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So

```
Limit[s[n], n -> Infinity]
(*
 0
*)
```

Comment: Thanks, seems this really goes to zero, which is not what I had expected.